# How to utilize package ggplot2 to plot maps with R

Tags: r, graphics, maps, ggplot2

I found the post [here](http://rpsychologist.com/parsing-data-from-a-text-file-and-plotting-where-people-live-using-ggplot2-and-openstreetmaps/) very interesting. However, my data is slightly different and therefore I need to make a few changes to make it work. Basically, I am stuck on the last part:

```
autoplot(mp) +
       geom_point(aes(x,y, size=people, color=people),
                  alpha = I(8/10), data=df.coords) +
       opts(axis.line=theme_blank(),axis.text.x=theme_blank(),
       axis.text.y=theme_blank(),axis.ticks=theme_blank(),
       axis.title.x=theme_blank(),
       axis.title.y=theme_blank()) +
      scale_size_continuous(range= c(1, 25)) + 
       scale_colour_gradient(low="blue", high="red") +
       opts(title="Where do we live?")
```

In my case, I don't use variables x, y at all. All I have is a .CSV file (quoted bellow) from which I need to extract variables 'occurences' and 'lat / long', and then use them appropriately to plot the map:

```
name    occurences  country.etc     pop     lat     long    capita
Uppsala 2           Sweden          128374  59.86   17.64   0
Vaxjo   10          Sweden          53994   56.88   14.80   0
```

Any input welcome!

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: I have managed to do the preprocessing, the aim of which is to build a CSV file like the one quoted above. The only thing missing now is to utilize function geom_poin() appropriately so that create the map...

Comment: So I'll ask again: what have you tried? Presumably lat and long will be your x and y variables, and you'll map size to occurences...? What's the problem?

Comment: @joran It works pretty fine now except that the cycles of the legend are in bold-black color, however, based on the tutorial, they should be colorful. Any ideas?